# Meteor templates #if block does not evaluate multiple optiopns

Tags: meteor, spacebars

I have an if statement which is checking for multiple roles as follows:

```
{{#if isInRole 'User' 'Admin'}}
    {{> dashboard}}
{{/if}}
```

This conditional if block only checks for the first option, and does not evaluate the second one. For example, when a User logs in the dashboard template is rendered correctly, but when an admin logs in it is not rendered. Is there a specific way to specify this OR condition?

Comment: Is the function `isInRole` expecting 1 or 2 arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this could be done like this when there are multiple options:

```
{{#if isInRole 'User, Admin'}}
   {{> dashboard}}
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine if you just name the arguments:

```
{{#if isInRole arg1='User' arg2='Admin'}}
  {{> dashboard}}
{{/if}}
```

You might have to amend your helper function to something that can handle arguments being passed in like that.  This would work:

```
...
isInRole: function(args) {
  return _.some(args.hash);
},
...
```

Note that the actual argument names are irrelevant, they just need to be supplied.